# Where can I download EverQuest for Mac?

Tags: macos, everquest

From reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EverQuest) and other sites, it seems that EverQuest can be played on Mac OS X. However, I have trouble finding a downloader. There's an [installer on CNet](http://download.cnet.com/EverQuest/3000-2097_4-10782556.html), but it doesn't seem to do anything except download a RTF file. I am new to Macs so maybe something's happening which I haven't noticed, but I doubt it.

Where can I download it?

Answer (score 3):

Taken from: http://www.eqmac.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4639

Step 3 is where you want to start.

Several of our readers have been having trouble getting the free download of Everquest's Mac edition from Sony Online Entertainment's site. So, here's some step-by-step instructions that should help:

**Step 1.** Sign up for a Station account* at http://www.station.sony.com/. If you already have a Station account for another SOE game, you can use that account, and skip to the next step.

**Step 2.** "Flag" your Station account for EQMac. This is best done by simply clicking on the "Free Digital Download" link for Everquest Mac Edition in the Station store. This will automatically download the "Launchpad" application for the next step.
(Replacement) Step 2:As of March 2009, there appears to be a problem using SOE's automated system to enable Station accounts for EQMac. The temporary fix is to contact SOE support directly, either by telephone (1-858-537-0898) or through their online chat support. You MUST have a live person enable the account for you. Hopefully, it will be fixed soon!

**Step 3.** Get a copy of the Everquest "Launchpad" application. You can either download it from http://eqplayers.station.sony.com/download/EverQuestLP.sit, or simply copy it from another computer. If you download it via the free digital download from Sony, it will have the extension ".sit" which means that it is compressed using the "Stuffit" application. You may need to download a free copy of Stuffit Expander to expand the compressed program.

**Step 4.** Set up your payment options in your Station/Everquest Mac Edition tab. You will need a credit card (or direct checking account debit) to play, even for the free trial.
New accounts are not charged for 15 days, which is your 15 day free trial period. After that, your credit card or other payment method will be used.
Note:SOE "Game Cards" do not work for Everquest Mac Edition!

**Step 5.** Download the full game by launching the "Launchpad" application, and logging in under your Station account. This will begin the 2GB+ download process which can take a long time, depending on your Internet connection speed.

*-Note: SOE's Station code uses non-standard web code. Browsers such as Safari and Opera, which are heavily standards compliant tend to choke on the Station code. Therefore, it is strongly advised that you use a browser which supports the non-standard code, such as Firefox or Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

You can download and install it from from [EverQuest for Mac website](https://lp.soe.com/eqmac/live/). You must have a Station account and be logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, Everquest for Mac was shutdown forever on November 18, 2013.